# How to bind Crystal Report using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, crystal-reports

i don't know how to bind crystal report using entity framework.Please help me with code.Shall be very thankful to you guys.

Comment: you are kidding right ? What do you not understand. You just cannot directly link EF tables to crystal reports.

Comment: m not kidding, i have made dataset but unable to right code on pageload of form to bind and load the report

Comment: that is then a different question. Are we supposed to smell that you are facing problems with datasets if your question is about EF ? This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly link EF tables with crystal reports.
What you can do is create datasets fill them with information from queries in EF and bind your crystal report to that dataset.

It is described over here :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/531776/Entity-Framework-and-Crystal-Reports-Entities-to-D

Answer (score -1):

Use this code solve your problem:
it creates a datasets and fills it with information from queries in EF and bind your crystal report to that dataset.

```
     ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
                DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
                SqlConnection sqlCon;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Example";
                sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TCS3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=sa;Password=sql2008");
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [FirstName],[MiddleName],[LastName],[CurrentSession] FROM [db].[dbo].[addmitionform1]", sqlCon);
                da.Fill(dt);
                ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
                rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
                rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
```